# Converting the characters of strings in a single column into lowercase and getting the updated dataframe with all columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple columns out of which one column has city names with first letter in uppercase. I want to see the all city names in this particular with lowercase letters and an updated data frame with all the existing columns.

Ex-

```
colA,colB,colC
Australia,Albany,23
Australia,Sydney,56
India,Delhi,67
India,Guntur,89
```

I want output as

```
colA,colB,colC
Australia,albany,23
Australia,sydney,56
India,delhi,67
India,guntur,89
```

I tried using 'dplyr::mutate_each' function but ended up like following

```
colB
albany   
sydney   
delhi    
guntur
```

Comment: Just change the `toupper` to `tolower` in the link above

Comment: @Sotos, @Japp; Apologies if I didn't convyed my question properly. Ms Jess has suggested the right code for which I got the exact result I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tolower` function should do the trick like so:

```
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(colB = tolower(colB)
```

Comment: Yeah, This helped me. Thank you so much @jess

Answer (score 2):

dataframe$column<-sapply(dataframe$column, tolower)

Comment: it worked for me thanks!